# I got "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch". And some mail servers rejected my emails

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exim, mx-record

I have searched for related information about my problems for a few months but I could not solve my problem by myself. My domain is thaihurbcollection.com. I added PTR record, changed MX record to match reverse DNS. I used online tools from mxtoolbox.com, www.dnscolos.com, etc. According to the knowledge I got from  Google, I think I did it correctly. Anyway I still got "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch". Finally, I think I need help from all of you here. The following is my DNS information:

```
ftp A   103.7.57.158    
mail    A   103.7.57.158    
ns1 A   103.7.57.158    
smtp    A   103.7.57.158    
ns2 A   103.7.57.158    
pop A   103.7.57.158    
thaihurbcollection.com. A   103.7.57.158    
www A   103.7.57.158    
thaihurbcollection.com. NS  ns1.thaihurbcollection.com. 
thaihurbcollection.com. NS  ns2.thaihurbcollection.com. 
thaihurbcollection.com. MX  10 ns1.thaihurbcollection.com.  
103.7.57.158    PTR ns1.thaihurbcollection.com. 
_dmarc  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; rua=mailto:spam-reports@thaihurbcollection.com" 
_domainkey  TXT "o=~"   
thaihurbcollection.com. TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:103.7.57.158 -all"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your records, they are correct.

Are you sure that your mail server is identifying itself as ns1.thaihurbcollection.com? And that all mail you are sending out is from @thaihurbcollection.com?

I'm a little concerned it looks like you are hosting your own DNS for your domain (ns1.thaihurbcollection.com) and running everything on the same server and IP address. This could be your problem. Do yourself a favor and move your DNS records back to your registrar or host. It's ok to host all your own FTP, mail, and webservers - but, you shouldn't be hosting your own DNS like this, it will only cause you problems.

Once your DNS records are mirrored at your registrar you can change the DNS server settings back to the registrar's provided servers. I recommend using a more standard name for your mail server like mail.thaihurbcollection.com. You'll have to contact your ISP that owns 103.7.57.158 and have them update the PTR record to point to mail.thaihurbcollection.com. Then for your domain, setup an A record for mail.thaihurbcollection.com, and update your MX records to point to mail.thaihurbcollection.com.

By the way, the PTR record you have in your DNS entries doesn't do anything. You can convert domain names to IPs, your ISP converts IPs to domain names. You own the domain, the ISP owns the IP address. The ISP controls where the reverse record points to.

I don't know if this is causing you any issues, but it looks really bad having your mail server be ns1.thaihurbcollection.com. A name like that alone can get you rejected.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Appleoddity. It is best to separate those services; DNS, WWW, Mail, etc. After doing SMTP test at mxtoolbox.com, I got "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch". Is there any specific configuration that I have missed. I didn't know about the algorithm that mxtoolbox.com is using to test SMTP Server. [This hyperlink is a test result from mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3Athaihurbcollection.com&run=toolpage#)

Answer (score 0):

now I got more information related to this problem. I installed a new server and configured a new domain. I also went to www.dnsstuff.com and did a test again. I found that the results from mxtoolbox.com and dnsstuff.com are different. In my opinion, I think there might be two reasons that caused the tool to show the message "SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch"; 1. the algorithm that mxtoolbox.com uses, 2. configurations of Exim (send mail program).

I think that the DNS record of a domain thaihurbcollection.com that I posted in the beginning, they are correct. Except in NS record that it have to point back to the registrar.

Thanks.